# How to load different Master&Detail view controllers on button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am new in Objective-C programming. I have developed an iPhone App and everything went Ok. Now I want to create the iPad version of the same App. 
I started creating a split view controller. The problem is that I am not figuring out how to manage the master and detail views. 
I want that my iPad version of the App behaves something like this:
When it is first run I want only to show the Master View Controller like in the photo:
[image]

And I want empty the part of the Detail View Controller. Also when the user changes the iPad orientation to portrait and the detail view controller is empty I want to show the Master view and not the detail view, otherwise is the detail view controller is not empty, on orientation I want to show the detail view.
Then onClick of the first Enter button in the Master View Controller I want to load a view for the Detail View just like in the photo:
[image]

Then on click of the button in the Detail View I want to load completely new Master and Detail Views :
[image]

I have read and seen different tutorials on managing split views but they all try to explain the use of Table View Controllers with Split View Controllers and I've nowhere found something similar to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you actually can leave the details view empty. I haven't tried it.  Instead, make a view-controller with only white empty view, and place it at first.

I recommends you to put UINavigationController on each pane, and push your custom VCs into each NCs. Then you can perform push/pop/swap sub-VCs in NCs.